# Is it possible to Apply Exchange Rates through the QuickBooks Web Connector?

Tags: quickbooks, qbxml

Basically, it doesn't appear to be possible to set the exchange rates to update automatically in the QuickBooks Desktop UI (Company > Manage Currency > Download Latest Exchange Rates) when in Multi Currency Mode.

I was wondering if there is a request I can put through the Web Connector that is analogous to the menu option in the UI outlined above, that way I could call the web connector regularly and emulate downloading the latest exchange rates as an automatic process?  If not downloading exchange rates, then applying them directly?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, there is no way to do this through the QuickBooks SDK/API.